a question about sum of first and second stirling number multiplied
$\displaylines{\text{I was trying to prove} \binom{n}{m} = \sum_{k}(-1)^{m-k}S(n+1, k+1)s(k,m) \quad \text{where $S$ is the second kind of Stirling and $s$ is the first kind of Stirling number.}
\\ \text{I used a known formula}  \quad s(n,m) = \sum_{k}^n (-1)^{m-k} \binom{k}{m} 
 s(n+1,k+1) } \\
\begin{align}
& \sum_{k}(-1)^{m-k}S(n+1, k+1)s(k,m) 
\\&= \sum_{k=m}^n(-1)^{m-k}S(n+1, k+1) \bigg( \sum_{j=m}^k (-1)^{m-j} \binom{j}{m} 
 s(k+1,j+1) \bigg)
\\&= \sum_{j=m}^n \bigg( \sum_{k=j}^n (-1)^{-k-j} S(n+1, k+1)s(k+1,j+1)\bigg) \binom{j}{m}\tag{1}
\\&= \sum_{j=m}^n \delta_{n,j} \binom{j}{m} = \binom{n}{m}
\end{align}
$
normally, I am familiar with:
$\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)S(k,m)(-1)^{n-k} =  \delta_{m,n} \tag{2}$
but at $(1)$ I intuitively I assumed :
$\sum_{k=0}^n S(n+1,k+1)s(k+1,j+1)(-1)^{n-j} =  \delta_{n,j} \tag{3} $
So my question is this: can $(3)$ be derived from $(2)$ or is it independently derived and what is the combinatorial verbal story behind $(3)$?
